# Не хочет получать MainActivity.this. Ошибка on a null object reference. Как исправить?

Tags: java, android

Обращаюсь из класса Timer.java к MainActivity

```
   public Timer(long millisInFuture, final long countDownInterval, final ITimerCallback callback, final Context context) {

        currentTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long time = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                callback.ontTimerNewValue(String.valueOf(time));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                callback.ontTimerNewValue("ОК");

                MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity(); 
                mActivity.soobshenie(); // тут обращение

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Сама функция в MainActivity

```
    public void soobshenie()
    {
        builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); // Тут ошибка
        builder2.setTitle("Важное сообщение!")
                .setMessage("Сообщение")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("ОК",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                click_ok();

                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder2.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Ошибка на builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project33, PID: 28150
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:115)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:313)
        at com.example.project33.MainActivity.soobshenie(MainActivity.java:221)
        at com.example.project33.Timer$1.onFinish(Timer.java:48)
        at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

К самому таймеру обращаюсь из MainActivity следующим образом:

```
    public void timer_pusk()
    {
        int min = 15000;
        int max = 27000;
        int diff = max - min;
        Random random = new Random();
        int timer_ot_do = random.nextInt(diff);
        timer_ot_do += min;
        new Timer(timer_ot_do, 1000, new Timer.ITimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void ontTimerNewValue(String value) {
                timer_vivod.setText(value);
            }
        }, MainActivity.this);
    }
```

Почему возникает ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: Жизненный цикл активностей управляется операционной системой, их нельзя создавать с помощью оператора `new`.

Comment: Добавил стек ошибок

Comment: Вы имеете в виду new при подключение класса таймера?

Comment: Имею ввижу `new MainActivity()`. Так нельзя.

Comment: А как необходимо грамотно обратиться из отдельного класса к функции мэйнактивити? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка из за отсутствующего контекста, которого нету у вашей "активности", так как вы создали ее сами.
Новая "Активность" вызывается через Intent, так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

так как в таймере есть контекст, можно вместо этого кода:

```
MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity(); 
mActivity.soobshenie(); // тут обращение
```

сделать так:

```
((MainActivity)context).soobshenie();
```

Comment: К сожалению Таймер не внутри MainActivity. Отдельный класс

Comment: Не заметил сразу, что контекст в таймер передается, поправил ответ.

Comment: Отлично! Так всё работает! ... Вот только таймер после запуска второй раз опять не передаёт. То есть первый раз проходит шикарно. А потом таже ошибка при повторном обращении. Подскажешь почему второй раз не передаёт context ?

Comment: Такая же ошибка не может быть. Советую использовать аннотации и проверки на null, что бы поменьше натыкаться на ошибки. Например `@NotNull final Context context`. Тогда IDE будет тебе немного помогать.

Comment: Подскажи а где такую штуку необходимо прописать @NotNull final Context context ? Над проблемной функцией?

Comment: @NotNull используй перед всеми параметрами своих функций, которые не могут быть null никогда и не при каких условиях, тогда IDE будет подсказывать тебе где ты не проверяешь переменные. Избавит от неожиданных ошибок.

Comment: Всё работает. Разобрался. Невнимательность сработала от радости)) Ещё раз спасибо! .. Подскажите а что значит обрамление такое в скобках - ((MainActivity)context)? Хочется понимать суть)

Comment: У этого контекста тип указан как `Context` необходимо привести его к `MainActivity` что бы вызвать `soobshenie()`. Но это источник ошибки конечно, если таймер вызовите с другой "активностью" (без метода "soobshenie"), приложение упадет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!